# How do I override Django's administrative change password page?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to override Django's administrative "Change Password" page (change_password.html).  As such, I've placed Django's "/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_change_form.html" in my project's "/templates/admin/registration/password_change_form.html" directory.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do the trick.

At this point, I'm stumped.  I'm guessing it has something to do with Django's /contrib/auth/urls.py file (which directs the the admin change password call to "django.contrib.auth.views.password_change"), but admin template changes have been trivial so far and I'm surprised this one doesn't follow suit.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does your settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS look like?

Comment: It has "'./templates',".  I'm not sure that's the problem.  I have a "/templates/admin" directory and that's not explicitly defined in the TEMPLATE_DIRS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick look at the source indicates you should place the template in:

```
/templates/registration/password_change_form.html
```

Note bene: there is no 'admin/' in there.

Comment: Where did you see that as the solution?  I must've overlooked it.

Comment: I read the source. Of course, on a second pass, I found it in the Djanog docs a http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.django.contrib.auth.views.password_change

Comment: Look at the parameter list of the function `password_change` in django/contrib/auth/views.py

Comment: Don't need to look at any of that, just look at the paths themselves.  There's no "admin/" after "templates/" in the original location of the file, why would you add one and expect it to work?

Comment: This is incorrect. The builtin contrib.admin has a template in that exact location, which will override any similarly named template in your custom project/app.

Answer (score 22):

You must use:

```
templates/registration/password_change_form.html
```

**If you still see the Django's Admin template**, you must change the order of your `INSTALLED_APPS` (e.g if your template is inside some app, this app must appear before `django.contrib.admin` in `INSTALLED_APPS`)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change

Comment: don't know why you got downvoted, this is the answer I was looking for. Problem solved!

Comment: The tipp **this app must appear before django.contrib.admin in INSTALLED_APPS** was very helpful!

Comment: Old though this comment is, it is still a life saver ;)
+1 for mentioning importance of order

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; I believe it has to do how django template loaders work.

If you are using something like

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

With something like
   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
   )

Then you would expect that (where localstore is the name of your local satchmo overrides) localstore/templates/registration/password_change_form.html would work. However, it doesn't for the password_change_form because the admin is overwriting it. So, it goes something like:

1. File loader template dirs (e.g. templates)
2. (django admin templates)
3. Local apps template dirs

So, the solution for me was to move my registration template overrides from my localstore/templates directory to the /templates directory of the project.